# TTimer Stops by itself

Tags: delphi, timer

I am using TTimer in my software and it supposed to run forever 24/7. Nowhere in my software is that timer disabled or stopped from running. It's main function is to update table's value. It is started as soon as the software is run and from that point on TTimer should not stop. However, after running for over a month, that TTimer mysteriously stops running. The software is run on Windows 7 and the software is developed on Delphi 2010 XE. I've searched my code to see what might be causing it, but I can't figure out what.

```
 Timer1.Enabled:=true;
```

That's how the timer is started.

UPDATE:
After doing some investigation, I found out that the TTimer never stopped, but there is another issue. My TStringGrid table on a TForm just simply don't show any values being updated. Further, I also found out that my TList List I am using to store list of data item is being destroyed somehow that the list becomes empty. But the data items in the list are not deleted anywhere in the code once they are loaded only when the program is started.

Everytime I update the TStringGrid on the form, I run through my TList items from 0 to count-1 location. So, if there is no item in the TList in the memory, my code simply skips
over the display part and thus nothing gets updated on the TStringGrid.

Something like:

```
If (List.count>0) then 
begin
//Display values in TStringGrid; 
end;
```

But while the software is still running, I was able to reload my list of items from a file
back into TList list and my software started to work like it supposed.

I hate to say the ugliest word programmers hate the most. I am afraid I may have a memory leak. Anyone think so?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know if the OnTimer event is not fired anymore?  I suggest you to log an entry on the very first line of the OnTimer event, run it for the time required until it stops working and check if it is not fired at all.  I see a high probability your own code is failing after the OnTimer event is fired.

Comment: @jachguate: I believe my real problem is memory leak. Do you have any suggestion for that.

Comment: @user639464 You can start by running your application in your development environment for a while with fastMM leak detection activated, but that's another question (probably already answered here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TTimer` is just a wrapper around the Windows [`SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx) API which I believe will run forever.

I suspect that the timer still runs, but the event handler that it fires is failing to operate as desired.

Comment: I believe my real problem is memory leak. Do you have any suggestion for that.

Comment: The facetious suggestion is to start freeing your memory once you have finished with it. But a memory leak wouldn't lead to a failure like this. Are you perhaps suffering from a resource/handle/GDI object leak? Anyway, you should ask a new question with some more information.

Answer (score 5):

I bet it stops 49 days after reboot. When Windows GetTickCount wraps around. Sure you're not doing a check that would fail based on this?

Comment: Erik, the `TTimer` component uses the SetTimer() function not the  `GetTickCount`.

Comment: @RRUZ: Yep, that's why I asked if he has checks

Comment: I believe my real problem is memory leak. Do you have any suggestion for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's stopping after a month; I'd suspect (as Erik said) you have something using GetTickCount() that's failing after the wraparound at ~49 days.

As a general rule, though, it's better to stop/start the timer to prevent a delay from causing a timer message to be dropped:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  try
    // Do whatever on timer event firing
  finally
    Timer1.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;
```

You might try this instead of just allowing it to run constantly; if it is a bug in the TTimer code (I don't see anything after a quick scan of XE's TTimer implementation), stopping and starting may reset things to prevent the failure.

Comment: I don't see how this could help. How would a timer event be dropped? This code might stop you being saturated with timer events. They don't get dropped though, they just get posted in the message queue.

Comment: If TTimer is based on WM_TIMER windows messages, multiple timer events will be coalesced into a single timer event if the function takes too long. I would suggest start and stop the timer just to prevent the 49 day failure!

Comment: @Gregor What 49 day failure? Do you have documentation that timers stop after 49 days?

Comment: @David No docs whatsoever, but odds are pretty good that starting and stopping the timer will reset 'whatever' is stopping the timer in the time period suggested by the OP (1 month).  In the very least its worth a try, but it will take a month or more to test :-)

Comment: @David, no they don't. WM_TIMER events are low priority, and will in fact get dropped rather than having multiple events posted to the message queue. Raymond Chen wrote a post about this a while back, I believe... I'll try and dig up a link.

Comment: @David, couldn't find the post I thought Raymond made. Read the remarks here, though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644902%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Ken - Is this it? ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/04/489028.aspx)): "WM_TIMER messages are generated on demand if there are any due timers. And since the message is "virtually posted", multiple calls coalesce, ..."

Comment: @Sertac, I think that's the one I was remembering, although I didn't find it with a quick search. Thanks!

Comment: @Ken What you describe as events getting dropped isn't really the problem. When they start being coalesced because you can't handle them fast enough, you get saturated and your CPU runs 100%. But I see what you mean. I think we are talking about the same issue. With me it never bothers me that they get dropped in your viewpoint, more that my program becomes non-responsive!

Comment: I don't know if timer implementation has changed any, but I doubt it has changed significantly. The original timer was implemented by setting a flag in the message queue structure for the app. When no other messages were pending, the flag is checked and if set a timer message is generated. So they don't "queue" or anything. But it won't cause 100% CPU or anything - that is just because the CPU is busy processing other messages or spending too much time handling the Timer message and not going back quick enough.

Comment: @David, I consider 'consolidated' the same as dropping; if 10 timer messages are generated, and because of their priority they're consolidated to 9, you still got one less than what was generated. The 10th one was 'dropped'. But I think you're right - we're talking about the same thing in the end. :)

Comment: @mj2008 you get 100% CPU if you process them slower than the rate at which they get posted.

Comment: I believe my real problem is memory leak. Do you have any suggestion for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should free memory allocated after the job is done:

`Timer1.FreeOnRelease()` or `.Free();`